# Change label text on right bar item swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have created a common nevigation method in view controller extension to show back, close and cart item on navigation bar through out my application. It shows the items on nav bar properly. But the cart item which is at the right side of the nav bar, has a button icon and a round badge icon with label. I need to update the label and increase the count on label every time an item is added in the cart. But somehow the label is not changing. Below is my code -

UIViewController Extension -

```
func setCartBarButtonItem() {
    let cartBarButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: getCartButton())
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cartBarButton
}

    func getCartButton() -> UIButton{

            let frame = CGRect.init(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, y: 14, width: 44, height:44)
            let cartButton = UIButton.init(frame: frame)
            cartButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "cart"), for: .normal)
            cartButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.cartButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
            let cartLabelView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: cartButton.layer.bounds.width/2, y: 10, width: 16, height: 16))
            cartLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 234.0/255.0, blue: 41.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cartLabelView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            cartLabelView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
            cartLabelView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 54.0/255.0, green: 54.0/255.0, blue: 54.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            cartButton.addSubview(cartLabelView)

            let cartLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: cartLabelView.layer.bounds.width/3, y: 0, width: cartLabelView.layer.bounds.width, height: cartLabelView.layer.bounds.height))
            cartLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            cartLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 9)
            cartLabelView.addSubview(cartLabel)
            cartLabelView.isHidden = true

                    var count = 0
                    count = getNumberOfItemInCart()
                    if count > 0 {
                        cartLabelView.isHidden = false
                        cartLabel.text = String(count)
                    }

            return cartButton
        }
```

In one delegate function which is called when item is added in cart, I call the this setCartBarButtonItem() to update the label. But label does not update. It shows the last value only.

Comment: Are you sure `cartLabel.text = String(count)` actually called?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Yes I check that, It is being called

Comment: Can you add `getNumberOfItemInCart ` method in your question as well.

Comment: That is simple core data call, I have put breakpoint and tested it. I am getting correct count but its just not updating the label text somehow.

Comment: So you are calling `setCartBarButtonItem()` method every time you update the count?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Yes!

Comment: Looks like thats the mistake here. Can you call `setCartBarButtonItem` in your `viewDidLoad` method and in your delegate it should only update the text of `cartLabel`.

Comment: I am calling setCartBarButtonItem in viewDidLoad. How can we only update cartLabel?

Comment: You can declare `cartLabel` outside the `getCartButton` method and inside the class so it will be accessible into other methods.

Comment: getCartButton is extension method, I can't declare cartLabel in extension

Comment: As you mentioned its `UIViewController Extension -` you can declare `cartLabel` into your `UIViewController` and you can access it in your `Extension`

Comment: I am using cartLabel at right bar button item from many view controllers, I don't wanna declare it in every view controllers.